# Scroll to anchor after CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an CSS animation like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
0% {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity: 0;} //This could be 90%
//And here could be frame for 100% which would scroll it down.
}
```

---

```
#headercover {
    -webkit-animation-name:flip;
-webkit-animation-duration:3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

---

I'd want the page to scroll down to an anchor, after the last frame of the animation.
I'm not really experienced in jQuery or JavaScript, so could you help me out?

See the site: [HERE](http://artotek.fi/mobiili_index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}, 3000); // wait 3000 ms
```

Comment: I had a syntax error, sorry, try it now. Remember to change ```#elementtoScrollToID``` to your correct ID

Comment: Got it working. Was actually missing jQuery itself :D